# Read from splunk source and write to topic - writing same record. not pulling latest records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, splunk

same record is being written to topic. not pulling latest records from splunk. time parameters are set in start method to pull last one min data. Any inputs.

currently i dont set offset from source. when poll is run every time, does it look for source offset and then poll? in logs can we have time as offset.

```
@Override
public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
    List<SourceRecord> results = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> recordProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (true) {
        try {
            String line = null;                
            InputStream stream = job.getResults(previewArgs);
            String earlierKey = null;
            String value = null;                                
            ResultsReaderCsv csv = new ResultsReaderCsv(stream);
            HashMap<String, String> event;    
            while ((event = csv.getNextEvent()) != null) {
                for (String key: event.keySet())   {                
                    if(key.equals("rawlogs")){
                        recordProperties.put("rawlogs", event.get(key));                                                        results.add(extractRecord(Splunklog.SplunkLogSchema(), line, recordProperties));
                        return results;}}}
            csv.close();
            stream.close();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred : " + ex);
        }
    }
}
private SourceRecord extractRecord(Schema schema, String line, Map<String, String> recordProperties) {
    Map<String, String> sourcePartition = Collections.singletonMap(FILENAME_FIELD, FILENAME);       
    Map<String, String> sourceOffset = Collections.singletonMap(POSITION_FIELD, recordProperties.get(OFFSET_KEY));
    return new SourceRecord(sourcePartition, sourceOffset, TOPIC_NAME, schema, recordProperties);        
}

@Override
public void start(Map<String, String> properties) {
    try {
        config = new SplunkSourceTaskConfig(properties);
    } catch (ConfigException e) {
          throw new ConnectException("Couldn't start SplunkSourceTask due to configuration error", e);
    }
    HttpService.setSslSecurityProtocol(SSLSecurityProtocol.TLSv1_2);
    Service service = new Service("splnkip", port);
    String credentials = "user:pwd";
    String basicAuthHeader = Base64.encode(credentials.getBytes());
    service.setToken("Basic " + basicAuthHeader);       
    String startOffset = readOffset();
    JobArgs jobArgs = new JobArgs();
    if (startOffset != null) {
        log.info("-------------------------------task OFFSET!NULL ");
        jobArgs.setExecutionMode(JobArgs.ExecutionMode.BLOCKING);
        jobArgs.setSearchMode(JobArgs.SearchMode.NORMAL);
        jobArgs.setEarliestTime(startOffset);
        jobArgs.setLatestTime("now");
        jobArgs.setStatusBuckets(300);
    } else {
        log.info("-------------------------------task OFFSET=NULL ");
        jobArgs.setExecutionMode(JobArgs.ExecutionMode.BLOCKING);
        jobArgs.setSearchMode(JobArgs.SearchMode.NORMAL);
        jobArgs.setEarliestTime("+419m");
        jobArgs.setLatestTime("+420m");
        jobArgs.setStatusBuckets(300);
    }

    String mySearch = "search host=search query";
    job = service.search(mySearch, jobArgs);        
    while (!job.isReady()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log.error("Exception occurred while waiting for job to start: " + ex);
        }
    }        
    previewArgs = new JobResultsPreviewArgs();
    previewArgs.put("output_mode", "csv");        
    stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);
}
```

Comment: Please share your connector configurations

Comment: in start method I set splunk credentials and search query and set below time parameters. JobArgs job = new JobArgs(); job.setEarliesttime=+419m; job.setLatesttime=+420m;  job = service.search("splunk search param", job); private JobResultsPreviewArgs previewArgs = new JobResultsPreviewArgs(); previewArgs.put("output_mode", "csv");          In the poll() method, define the stream and process the record. InputStream stream = job.getResults(previewArgs); when I display the processed line, it keeps on repeating same record.

Comment: @cricket_007 My assumption is when poll method runs, it polls the last one minute from now and get new records always. but what I see is it always repeats just one entry.

Comment: 1) edit your question to include formatted code 2) I don't recognize those methods, but it's not the Kafka API, and I don't know Splunk that well. But no, Kafka does not rewind a minute, it defaults to only read new data

Comment: my code mimicks from https://github.com/kanagha/Kafka-SplunkSourceConnector/blob/master/src/splunk/source/connector/SplunkSourceTask.java  . You can take a look at this one too.

Comment: All I can say is that `poll` is called repeatedly itself, so you do not need a loop. You also need a way to track "progress" from the source, so you cannot just keep running the same query and expect different results.

Comment: ok. in our logs, we have timestamp through which we can track the status how much it has been consumed so far. can I store the timestamp in source_offset and do I need to have logic to read from point after that timestamp when each time the poll is called. so source_offset determines from which point it should poll the data from source. Is my understanding right.

Comment: @cricket_007 I was able to generate new data from splunk. But when I do results.add(extractRecord(schema,line,recordProperties) - I see if there are 10 records the last record being written 10 times.  in SourceRecord method,  
 return new SourceRecord(sourcePartition, sourceOffset, TOPIC_NAME, Splunklog.SCHEMA, recordProperties);     recordProperties is a hash map and contains the log content.

Comment: Sorry, I've not written a source connector to really be much help here. I will say that you shouldn't put a return in a loop before you close the resources you're looping over

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007